# How to give user option to move Knight in chess based game?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a school assignment wherein the purpose is to simulate the movement of a knight on a chessboard. The first part where the knight moves randomly is all good but the second part where the user gets to choose movement is giving me a headache. Since we have a break over the holidays I can't get help in school.

```
from random import choice
#From the module random imports the random choice option

class Point: #Class for a point on the board

    def __init__(self, xCoord, yCoord):#Coordinates of a position on the board
        self.xCoord = xCoord #x-coordinate, i.e. row
        self.yCoord = yCoord #y-coordinate, i.e. column

    def getCoordinates(self):
        return (self.xCoord, self.yCoord) #Returns coordinates for point on board

    def getOffsetCoordinates(self, i = 65):
        return (chr(self.xCoord + i), self.yCoord + 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.getCoordinates()) #Returns the coordinates in a string
        return str(self.getLegalPoints())

class Board: #Class for the board

    def __init__(self): #Creates the board using matrices
        self.rows = [] #A list which will be used as a base for the rows
        for x in range(8): #Adds 8 columns in which every 
            column = []
            for y in range(8):
               column.append(0)
            self.rows.append(column)

    def getBoard(self):
        return self.rows #Returns rows, aka the board

    def setPointTaken(self, point, stepnumber):
        x,y = point.getCoordinates()
        self.rows[x][y] = stepnumber


    def __str__(self):
        boardString = ""
        boardString += "     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\n"
        for i in range(len(self.rows)):
            currentRow = self.rows[i]
            boardString += " |" + chr(65 + i) + "| "
            for j in range(len(currentRow)):
                elementString = str(currentRow[j])
                elementStringAdjusted = elementString.ljust(2)
                boardString += elementStringAdjusted + " "
            boardString += "\n"        
        return boardString

def getLegalPoints(currentPosition, board):

    possiblePoints = []
    legalPoints = []
    stringlegalPoints = str(legalPoints)
    originX, originY = currentPosition.getCoordinates()
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX + 1, originY + 2))
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX + 1, originY - 2))
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX - 1, originY - 2))
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX - 1, originY + 2))
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX + 2, originY + 1))
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX + 2, originY - 1))
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX - 2, originY - 1))
    possiblePoints.append(Point(originX - 2, originY + 1))

    for point in possiblePoints:
        x, y = point.getCoordinates()
        if 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and not board.rows[x][y]:
            legalPoints.append(point)

    return legalPoints
    return strlegalPoints


def main():
    playType = None
    while playType != 1 or playType != 2:
        playType = int(input("\n""This program shows the path of a knight on a chessboard." "\n" + "[1] - Random path" "\n" + "[2] - Make your own path" + "\n" + "Choose option 1 for a random path or option 2 to create your own!" "\n"))
        if playType == 1:
            board = Board()
            startLetter = input("Choose a row (A-H): ").upper()
            startNumber = input("Choose a number (1-8): ")
            xCoord = ord(startLetter)-65
            yCoord = (int(startNumber) - 1)
            startPoint = Point(xCoord, yCoord)
            stepnumber = 1
            board.setPointTaken(startPoint, stepnumber)
            legalPoints = getLegalPoints(startPoint, board)
            while legalPoints != None:
                stepnumber += 1
                nextPosition = choice(legalPoints)
                board.setPointTaken(nextPosition, stepnumber)
                legalPoints = getLegalPoints(nextPosition, board)
                if len(legalPoints) <= 0:
                    break
            print(board)
            print("Last visited square: ",nextPosition.getOffsetCoordinates(),"\n" "Number of steps: ",stepnumber,"\n")

            break
        elif playType == 2:
            board = Board()
            startLetter = input("Choose a row (A-H): ").upper()
            startNumber = input("Choose a number (1-8): ")
            xCoord = ord(startLetter)-65
            yCoord = (int(startNumber) - 1)
            startPoint = Point(xCoord, yCoord)
            stepnumber = 1
            board.setPointTaken(startPoint, stepnumber)
            legalPoints = getLegalPoints(startPoint, board)
            while legalPoints != None:
                print(str(legalPoints))
                stepnumber += 1
                nextPosition = input("Choose your next square among those presented: ")
                board.setPointTaken(nextPosition, stepnumber)
                legalPoints = getLegalPoints(nextPosition, board)
                print(board)
                print(nextPosition.getOffsetcoordinates(), "\n" "Number of steps: ",stepnumber,"\n")
                if len(legalPoints) <= 0:
                    break
            break


main()
```

Here's what I have so far. I tried reusing the movement for the random path for creating the personalized path but I can't figure out how to print out the allowed movements without it showing up like so:

```
[<__main__.Point object at 0x03915030>, <__main__.Point object at 0x03915090>, <__main__.Point object at 0x039150B0>, <__main__.Point object at 0x039150D0>, <__main__.Point object at 0x039150F0>, <__main__.Point object at 0x03915110>, <__main__.Point object at 0x03915130>, <__main__.Point object at 0x03915150>]
Choose your next square among those presented:
```

From what I've understood I should be having the legalpoints function in a class to get it represented as a string. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? I'm a complete novice and if I'm breaking any rules please remove this post.

Answer (score 0):

One way to print the list of Point objects is by changing the `Point.__str__` method to `__repr__`. That way [(1, 4), (1, 0), (2, 3), (2, 1)] will be printed instead of something like `[<__main__.Point object at 0x03915030>, ...]`. Be careful! That representation looks like a tuple of two integers. I would personally change that to something else. (If you don't want to change __str__ to __repr__, you could use a for loop like `for i in legalPoints: print(i)`)

The `board.setPointTaken` method expects a Point object as its first argument, but you are passing a string to it since `input` returns a string.

Assuming that the user will enter the new square in a format like `(1, 4)`, you can fix this by replacing the line `nextPosition = input("Choose your next square among those presented: ")` with the following two lines:

```
nextPosition_str = input("Choose your next square among those presented: ")
nextPosition = Point(*(int(k) for k in nextPosition_str[1:-1].split(',')))
```

You'll have to edit that in case you're expecting the user to enter the square in a format like `B6` or so.

You also have a typo in the line `print(nextPosition.getOffsetcoordinates(), "\n" "Number of steps: ",stepnumber,"\n")`. The name of the method has a capital C, so it should be `getOffsetCoordinates()`.